# jQuery 'change' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onchange

How to detect changing of a text field when user inserts a text from the clipboard using mouse (trackpad)? 'change', 'keyup', 'click' events are not fired in this case. How it is done on Twiiter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no traditional events work, you may have to set up some kind of polling system:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        if (this.value != $.data(this, 'oldVal')) {
            $(this).trigger('change');
        }
    }, 250);
}).change(function(){
    $.data(this, 'oldVal', this.value);

    // do your onchange code here
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try subscribing to `paste` event:

- [MDC reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onpaste)
- [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536955(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: well ... `onpaste` is more or less the same as `keyup`, just that 2 keys were pressed :). you can minimize change-events to `keyup` and `click`

Comment: @Andreas: Try to paste a text using a context-menu (right click and select "Paste"). Neither "keyup" not "click" will fire.

Comment: @volpav: i used `click` too generic - my mistake ... `mousedown` captures all sorts of clicks (whether it's left, middle, right ...)

Comment: @Andreas: what if you navigate to the field using TAB ? Then press the "Context menu" button on your keyboard - the context-menu will appear :-)

Comment: @volpav: this is an event which could be handled by `keyX` (`X` for one of `up`, `down`, `press` - dunno which exactly). otherwise why not use `blur` (which solves any approach)? you can combine `blur` with `defaultValue` to track changes...

Comment: @Andreas: I just wanted to point that there is no "straightforward" (or "working in all cases" if you will) approach.

Comment: @volpav: there is ... just see my answer!

Comment: @Andreas: Okay, maybe it's just a matter of the type of interaction that is required. If you need to do something right after the user has changed the value (and not when the field lost the focus) then the "blur" won't help.

Comment: @volpav: for this case the question should be elaborated!

Comment: @Andreas, well no, but I think we've concluded that `onpaste` is quite different to a combination of `keyup` and `mousedown` ;)

Answer (score 0):

i would use `blur` for this

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Eqryx/)

```
var control = $('#txt');
control.blur(function() {
    var defaultValue = control.attr('defaultValue');
    var actualValue = control.val();
    if (defaultValue != actualValue) {
        control.css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Comment: @Azat: and were is your condition/requirement for that? :)